# Magento 2.4 CE Is there a native customer credit module?

Tags: magento

There is a Credit Balance on the back-end->Customer Information. But it seems not functional on CE 2.3. Should I tweak parameters in Admin to enable it? Or do I simply need to upgrade to 2.4?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: OK. Thanks for the tip. Are you a robot ?